# How to correctly convert Unix Timestamp with timezone offset into Apex Datetime?

Tags: apex, datetime

There is a webservice which I'm trying to integrate in Salesforce. The webservice returns a date time in format like this

```
/Date(1569301200000-0500)/
```

I believe this is Unix Timestamp, and we can convert it into Apex Datetime using `Datetime.newInstance( Long.valueOf( '1569301200000' ) )`

But I'm missing the extra `-0500` also in here and I'm not able to compensate for this. Can someone guide me how to accurately read the datetime in APEX with this format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to this [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Two_digit_years_map_to_1900_-_1999)

> ### The Unix epoch and timestamps
>
> A JavaScript date is fundamentally specified as the number of
> milliseconds that have elapsed since midnight on January 1, 1970, UTC.
> This date and time is called the ***Unix epoch***, which is the predominant
> base value for computer-recorded date and time values.
>
> **Note**: It's important to keep in mind that the date and time is stored
> in the local time zone, and that the basic methods to fetch the date
> and time or its components all work in the local time zone as well.

You can use [this](https://www.epochconverter.com/) online datetime converter to check the date and time.

`1569301200000-0500` is not Unix epoch but only `1569301200000` is, and it converts to below:

[image]

Also `Datetime.newInstance( Long.valueOf( '1569301200000' ) )` returns ***2019-09-24 05:00:00***

Perhaps `0500` is just indicating that its 5am in GMT or else `-0500` could be time correction to get local time for which you can use [DateTime.addHours or DateTime.addMinutes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm). In any case you need to get clarification from the webservice developers regarding what is *0500*